# How to set z-index of marker in SyncFusion Maps Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion

Is there any way to set z-index for marker in SyncFusion Maps? I have few different events which occurred on the same geo position and I need to see them all. Now I could see only single and I don't know what exactly first or last?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no direct option available to get the z-index of the marker. However, you can change the marker rendering order based on the given index using the insertMarker, removeMarkerAt methods in the MapTileLayerController. We have added a code example for your reference.

https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/maps/markers#adding-markers-dynamically

```
class _MarkerPageState extends State<MarkerPage> {
  late MapZoomPanBehavior _zoomPanBehavior;
  late MapTileLayerController _controller;
  final TextEditingController _insertTextController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _replaceTextController = TextEditingController();
  int _markerSwapIndex = -1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _zoomPanBehavior = MapZoomPanBehavior(
        focalLatLng: MapLatLng(15.9129, 79.7400), zoomLevel: 3);
    _controller = MapTileLayerController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _insertTextController.dispose();
    _replaceTextController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(‘Marker sample’)),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: SfMaps(
              layers: [
                MapTileLayer(
                  urlTemplate: ‘https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png’,
                  zoomPanBehavior: _zoomPanBehavior,
                  controller: _controller,
                  initialMarkersCount: 5,
                  markerBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return MapMarker(
                      latitude: 20.5937,
                      longitude: 78.9629,
                      size: Size(30, 30),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          color: Colors.teal,
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            _markerSwapIndex != -1
                                ? _markerSwapIndex.toString()
                                : index.toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _markerSwapIndex = -1;
                  _controller.insertMarker(_controller.markersCount);
                },
                child: Text(‘Add marker’),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(‘Replace marker index'),
                  Container(
                    width: 50,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: _replaceTextController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      onChanged: (String text) {
                        if (text.isNotEmpty) {
                          int index = int.parse(_replaceTextController.text);
                          _markerSwapIndex = index;
                          // Add index less than the [_controller.markersCount].
                          _controller.removeMarkerAt(index);
                          _controller.insertMarker(_controller.markersCount);
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text('Insert marker index'),
                  Container(
                    width: 50,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: _insertTextController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      onChanged: (String text) {
                        if (text.isNotEmpty) {
                          int index = int.parse(_insertTextController.text);
                          _markerSwapIndex = index;
                          // Add index less than the [_controller.markersCount].
                          _controller.insertMarker(_controller.markersCount);
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In addition to that, you can group the marker based on the zoom level as shown in the following KB.

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/12639/how-to-group-the-markers-based-on-zoom-level